# how to change the value of listview item after the lines that i want to edit in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, vb.net-2010

http://s136.beta.photobucket.com/user/dheorwyne/media/Capture.jpg.html

Hi, this is a sample Pay Schedule generated dates.. the last column is indicated the status which is CLOSED, OPENED..

all i want is after the OPENED value.. the next Line change to = "FUTURE ENTRY"

My idea s is search first the OPENED string to subitems then the process after the next line.. The problem is i Dont know how to code that kind of logic..

Or any way to simply to do it..

Ex:

CLOSED
OPENED
FUTURE ENTRY

something like this..

Thank You

Sample code populating item to Listview from Database

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
sqlSTR = "select * from tblpayschedule " & str
ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)
Dim myRow As DataRow
Dim x As Integer = 0
For Each myRow In sqlDT.Rows
    ListView1.Items.Add(myRow.Item(0))
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(1))
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(2))
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(3))
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(4))
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(5))
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(6))
Next
```

Comment: Hi Deorwin, you'll need to add some source code. Ideally, the part where the data is added into the grid.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Do you want FUTURE ENTRY to appear on a line by itself below every "OPENED"? Do you want to know how to search a listview column for the first "OPENED" and then iterate through the rest of the listview items?

Comment: yes sir.. something like that.. only one OPENED then next line is FUTURE ENTRY

ex:
CLOSED
CLOSED
CLOSED
CLOSED
OPENED
FUTURE ENTRY
FUTURE ENTRY
FUTURE ENTRY
FUTURE ENTRY
FUTURE ENTRY